# NativeScript Tabs Height

Tags: tabs, nativescript, tabview

Is there anyway to customize the actual tabs height/margin/padding?

all properties I tried  work on tabView Container only. And there is no clear documentation on how to do it either.

https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_tab_view_.tabview

[Tabs Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpY25.png)

Comment: You may hide the default TabBar and use your custom layout for tab icons. Highlight selected based on selectedIndex of TabView.

Comment: I ended up implementing my own Tabview & ActionBar. 
The funny thing is the ui widgets for ActionBar & TabBar are taking 1/4 of the screen's height on my device. 
 so I wonder why bother having these widgets if they are not open for simple customization.

Comment: This will be greatly improved in the next release 6.0